# Python function introspection: what members of a class passed as argument are mentioned inside it?

Tags: python, function, introspection, higher-order-functions, inspect

Say that I have a function like the following:

```
def eggs(a,b,c):
    if c.foo:
        return a + b.bar
    else:
        return c.spam
```

I'd like to have a higher order function capable of introspecting the function passed and retrieve what members of an argument are mentioned inside the code via the dot syntax, with the following behavior:

```
>>> member_inspector(eggs, 'c')
('foo','spam')

>>> member_inspector(eggs, 'b')
('bar')

>>> member_inspector(eggs, 'a')
()
```

Can this be done? How?

Comment: To what degree to you want to take this? What about `getattr(c, 'b' + 'a' + 'r')`? Or `def eggs(c, p): getattr(c, p)`. These examples are only evaluated at runtime and cannot be introspected.

Comment: Good question. I'm not interesed in methods called via getattr or other corner cases. I'm only considering the member resolution via the dot syntax.

Comment: What if the function does something like `foo = c` and then accesses `foo.spam`?

Comment: Then `member_inspector(eggs, 'c')` returns `()`. I'm not interested in backtracking variable assignments (unless someone comes up with a very simple way to include it as a plus)

Comment: @FedericoRosato. Dot syntax is a short hand for calling `__getattribute__`

Comment: @MadPhysicist It sure is. I'm referring to the fact that a textual inspection of the code of the function passed should only care about the dot syntax.

Comment: Makes sense. Have a clearly delimited rabbit hole. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a basic version:

```
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent
import ast

def member_inspector(f, var):
    source = dedent(inspect.getsource(f))
    module = ast.parse(source)
    func = module.body[0]
    result = []
    for stmt in func.body:
        for node in ast.walk(stmt):
            if (isinstance(node, ast.Attribute) and
                    isinstance(node.value, ast.Name) and
                    node.value.id == var):
                result.append(node.attr)
    return result
```

Comment: Could I ask you for a bit of explanation, maybe some links to the `ast` module docs, and maybe even a "caveats" section? (Doesn't work if the function's source code can't be accessed, doesn't detect attribute access with `getattr` or `vars` or `__dict__`, gets tripped up by assignments like `foo = c; c.bar`, if the same attribute is accessed twice it's included in the output twice, etc.) Your code is good, but the answer is not.